# Angular 9: Karma Test debugging in library with WebStorm

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, webstorm, angular9

Does anybody here have problems when trying to debug an Angular library with WebStorm? I am trying to create a Karma test to test my service, but unfortunately since the last Angular Update debugging is not possible since my breakpoint is not reached.

The test section in my angular.json is the following:

```
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "projects/laps-expression-language-engine/src/test.ts",
        "tsConfig": "projects/laps-expression-language-engine/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "projects/laps-expression-language-engine/karma.conf.js",
        "sourceMap": true
      }
    },
```

My tsconfig.spec.js is the following:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
 "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.800.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0",
```

The following is the output of WebStorm when I execute a test with debugging:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\laps-core\Frontend\laps-web-core\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng test laps-expression-language-engine --karma-config "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2019.3\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellij.conf.js" --source-map
intellij: a browser for tests debugging will be captured automatically
11 02 2020 10:49:09.055:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
11 02 2020 10:49:12.682:INFO [Chrome 80.0.3987 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket B_IWlYkZdnKTE6BnAAAA with id manual-6210
```

The strange thing is, my tests are working and debugging has worked before updating Angular. Also I am able to debug a normal Angular application with attaching to the port. It is just not working when I am trying to debug Karma tests, any ideas what to do?

Comment: debugging library tests works fine for me when using Angular 9 ('9.0.0-rc.9') with similaar setup, I don't even need setting `"sourceMap": true` in `angular.json`, as WebStorm is passing this option in CLI anyway... Does debugging work in Chrome? Once the karma server is started, press **Debug** button in browser page to open http://localhost:9876/debug.html, then open Dev Tools and try locating your test sources in the *Sources* tab - can you see your .ts files there? Do breakpoints work?

Comment: Yeah correct, source mapping is passed from WebStorm anyway, I saw that in the logs. I can debug if I am using the browser, the files are as expected under karma_webpack but with webstorm that seems not be possible

Comment: can you reproduce it with a new project? Sample app the issue can be repeated with would be helpful